# Can't see symlink target

Tags: windows-10, symbolic-link

I'm trying to see the target of these symlinks/shortcuts in Windows 10.

I tried these instructions:

```
Right click column, More, Link Target
```

[image]

But the "Link target" column is empty.

I also used the `dir` command inside powershell, but also came up empty.

Note that these symlinks all work. When I double click them, they take me to a folder with contents.

Comment: What does `fsutil reparsepoint query` say about these items?

Comment: @user1686 That worked. If you submit answer I accept.

Comment: It was not an answer; it was a question.

Comment: @user1686 When I run it on one of the folders, the "Print Name" shows `C:\Users\username\projects\react-financial-charts\packages\annotations`, which definitely appears correct.

Answer (score -1):

You may be able to open the Properties dialog, to determine the target.

Comment: I only get the tooltip "Date created". Nothing else.

Comment: Answer changed, as I believe that natively, symlinks have no icon overlay, but must be provided by some Explorer extension, which you did not mention.

Comment: I'm using default Windows 10. The properties dialog shows no path.